# ServiceStack authentication request fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

I am trying to set up authentication with my ServiceStack service by following [this tutorial](http://enehana.nohea.com/general/customizing-iauthprovider-for-servicestack-net-step-by-step/).

My service is decorated with the `[Authenticate]` attribute.

My AppHost looks like this:

```
public class TestAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public TestAppHost() : base("TestService", typeof(TestService).Assembly) { }

    public static void ConfigureAppHost(IAppHost host, Container container)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties.
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

            // Configure the IOC container
            IoC.Configure(container);

            // Configure ServiceStack authentication to use our custom authentication providers.
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            host.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() =>
                new AuthUserSession(),  // use ServiceStack's session class but fill it with our own data using our own auth service provider
                new IAuthProvider[] { 
                    new UserCredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings)
                }));
        }
   }
```

where `UserCredentialsAuthProvider` is my custom credentials provider:

```
public class UserCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            // Authenticate the user.
            var userRepo = authService.TryResolve<IUserRepository>();
            var user = userRepo.Authenticate(userName, password);

            // Populate session properties.
            var session = authService.GetSession();
            session.IsAuthenticated = true;
            session.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            session.DisplayName = user.FullName;
            session.UserAuthName = session.UserName = user.Username;
            session.UserAuthId = user.ID.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ... Log exception ...
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In my user tests I initialize and start my TestAppHost on `http://127.0.0.1:8888`, then use JsonServiceClient to authenticate itself to the service like so:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://127.0.0.1:8888/")
var response = client.Send<AuthResponse>(new Auth 
{ 
    provider = UserCredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = username, 
    Password = password,
    RememberMe = true
});
```

But getting the following exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](Object request)...
```

The `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth` request contains the correct username and passsword, and the request is being posted to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/json/syncreply/Auth
```

I am not sure why the URL is not `/json/auth/credentials` or what I might be doing wrong. Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

Tracing the chain of events up the stack I found the following:

`JsonDataContractSerializer.SerializeToStream` correctly serializes the Auth request into Json. However, the `System.Net.HttpRequestStream` passed to `JsonDataContractDeserializer` by `EndpointHandlerBase` has a stream of the correct length that is filled with nulls (zero bytes). As a result, the request object passed to `CredentialsAuthProvider.Authenticate` has nulls in all its properties.

How can the HTTP stream get stripped of its data?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!!

The problem was the following pre-request filter that I added for logging purposes in `TestAppHost.Configure`:

```
        PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
        {
            LastRequestBody = httpReq.GetRawBody();
        });
```

as seen [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/BufferedRequestTests.cs).

When the `GetRawBody()` method reads the request InputStream it leaves it in the EOS state, and all subsequent read attempts return nothing.

So obviously `GetRawBody()` can only be safely used with buffered streams, but unfortunately it quietly causes a very nasty bug instead of throwing an exception when used  with a non-buffered stream.

Comment: Right all requests need to be buffered [see this answer for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17514953/85785).

Comment: Here's @mythz's explanation in another thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514754/can-servicestack-runner-get-request-body/17514953#17514953