# GetRawBody() is returning empty for REST requests

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to write the Raw data of my ServiceStack webservice using  servicerunner. This is working for SOAP requests but for the REST request GetRawBody() is returning empty.

```
public override void BeforeEachRequest(IRequest requestContext, T request)
    {
        Logger.Write(requestContext.GetRawBody());
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual HTTP verb you're using -- GET? POST?  REST is an architectural style, not a defined protocol.  Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514754/can-servicestack-runner-get-request-body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default web servers only provide a forward-only Request Stream which you can tell ServiceStack to skip deserialization so you can read from the Request Stream by [implementing IRequiresRequestStream on your Request DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream):

```
public class MyRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Which will inject the Request Stream instead of deserializing the Request DTO, e.g:

```
public class object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    var requestBody = request.RequestStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes();
}
```

Otherwise if you want ServiceStack to deserialize the Request and you want to re-read from the Request Body later yourself you need to tell ServiceStack to [buffer the Request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#buffering-the-request-and-response-streams) using a pre-request filter:

```
appHost.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
    httpReq.UseBufferedStream = true;
});
```